# Do the iPad 2 and the 6th generation iPod Nano have the same docking connector?

Tags: ipad, ipod-nano, lightning

I am looking to purchase a Speaker docking system for an iPad2, I also want to be able to use a 6th generation iPod Nano with the same dock connection.

Is the connection on the iPad 2 the same as the connection on the iPod Nano?

Answer (score 1):

The iPod Nano 6th gen uses a 32 pin connector, the same found on iPod classic, iPhones, and more importantly in your case the iPad/2  you will find all the specficatons for docks on the [Apple support website](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1380). Although it doesn't mention the 6th gen Nano.

This omission makes things slightly unclear however if you check out the [product description for the Apple dock connector to USB cable](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MA591G/B) you will see it is compatible with the 6th Gen iPod nano.